# How do I access a Silverlight XAP file across a domain?

Tags: silverlight, cross-domain

I'm trying to add my Silverlight application that lives on one subdomain to a web page in another subdomain. For some reason this just plain isn't working ... my Silverlight application is loaded as such in a page on http://subA.domain.com/somepage.html:

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
        width="800px" height="600px">
        <param name="source" value="http://subB.domain.com/SilverlightApp.xap" />
        <param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
        <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="2.0.31005.0" />
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <param name="enableHtmlAccess" value="true" />
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=124807" style="text-decoration: none;">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
                style="border-style: none" />
        </a>
    </object>
    <iframe style='visibility: hidden; height: 0; width: 0; border: 0px'></iframe>
</div>
```

If I move SilverlightApp.xap to subA.domain.com, it loads perfectly. What steps are needed to access a XAP file across domains?? I've been scraping the net trying to figure this out and seem to be getting nowhere.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Silverlight requests a .XAP file cross-domain, the content type must be: **application/x-silverlight-app**.  Also, you need a **cross-domain policy file** on the other domain. gl

Answer (score 5):

To assist others who have this same issue, and don't want to use IFrames, please see this [link](http://blog.dynamicprogrammer.com/2009/06/10/MakingSureYourSilverlight2WidgetWillWorkInACrossDomainScenario.aspx), as it has solved my problem. Even though the author is referring to Silverlight 2, it has solved my problem in Silverlight 3.  In case the link goes down, there are 2 things I needed to do:

-- In the Silverlight app, edit the AppManifest.xml to add the following:

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
ExternalCallersFromCrossDomain="ScriptableOnly">
```

-- If you are using HtmlPage in your Silverlight app (such as when reading the QueryString passed to the hosting page), you must also add:

```
<param name="enableHtmlAccess" value="true" />
```

to the silverlight object in the hosting page.

Please note there are security implications to the above, and I can't help but to think this is why Microsoft does not go out of their way to disseminate this information.  However in my case I don't have scriptable silverlight elements, and since I wrote the silverlight app, I don't have a problem with the hosting page allowing the silverlight app access to it.

While researching this, I noticed that this issue and corresponding solutions gets confused with a separate problem, the problem of a silverlight xap accessing a wcf service across domain boundaries.  That issue does require a clientaccesspolicy.xml file located on the root of the website hosting the wcf service.

So it is possible to have the 1st site accessing a xap file on a 2nd site, which accesses a data service on a 3rd site, for maximum flexibility and re-use.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple html file next to the .xap that contains the silverlight object and access this from an iframe. This is how http://silverlight.live.com/ fixed this issue for example.

On you main page on subA.domain.com add an iframe that show a html page on the other domain:

```
<iframe src="http://subB.domain.com/SilverlightApp.html" 
        scrolling="no" 
        frameborder="0" 
        style="width:800px;height:600px">
</iframe>
```

and SilverlightApp.html on subBdomain.com could look something like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">    
      <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
              type="application/x-silverlight-2"        
              width="800px" height="600px">        
        <param name="source" value="http://subB.domain.com/SilverlightApp.xap" />
        <param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
        <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="2.0.31005.0" />
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <param name="enableHtmlAccess" value="true" />
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=124807" 
           style="text-decoration: none;">            
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" 
               alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
               style="border-style: none" />
        </a>
      </object>
      <iframe style='visibility: hidden; height: 0; width: 0; border: 0px'>
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```